# Javascript: Functions with parameters

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a javacript function with parameters.

I am trying to create a page that has the following.

A function called diff() which takes two numbers as parameters and returns the difference between them (as a positive number) to the calling function.

&

A function called inOut() which is triggered by the user, collects user input, passes these to the first function, then outputs the result to the screen.

It would be great if someone could give me a start.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated

Many Thanks

```js
function diff(num1, num2) {

  if num1 > num2 {
    return num1 - num2
  } else {
    return num2 - num1
  }

  alert('The difference between the two numbers are')
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
    function diff(num1, num2) {

      if num1 > num2 {
        return num1 - num2
      } else {
        return num2 - num1
      }

      alert('The difference between the two numbers are')
    }
  </script>


  <p>Enter your values</p>

  <input id="num1" type="number" placeholder=" Value 1"></input>
  <input id="num2" type="number" placeholder=" Value 2"></input>
  <button onclick="diff(num1, num2)">Press for Answer</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

I know its not much but its all i have got at the moment :)

Comment: You can help yourself by showing us the code you have so far

Comment: Hello James, I'm sorry your question is not precise enough. You should try to focus on your issues step by step. First, you seem to have an issue on where to place scripts, then I'm not sure you know how to call the functions inside your scripts,...

Comment: These types of question should not be asked here, research first before asking. There are tons of examples on how to use functions

Comment: In the end, your question looks like "Hi, I don't want to spend time learning, please solve my issues as well".

Comment: as much as i do agree with everyone, I should have made it clearer that i am extremely new to JS and have have been confused by my research so i thought that someone might be willing to give me a helping hand to start off. @BonMacalindong

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe you were also meant to be tagged :). Also please take into consideration that I am very grateful for any help.

Comment: @JamesM That's the reason why I did not downvote. Now that your question is far better, I've upvoted it. I believe that SO should not be the place for high level questions only. Thank you for making questions that other users will be able to reuse.

Answer (score -1):

In the diff() function you return before calling the alert() function. Thats why it's not called. You could store the result in a variable and then pass the result into the alert().

```
function diff(num1, num2) {
  var result;
  if num1 > num2 {
    result = num1 - num2
  } else {
    result = num2 - num1
  }

  alert('The difference between the two numbers are: ' + result)
}
```

Edit: Sorry bout that, this should work. You also need to get the values of num1 and num2.

```
  <script>
  function diff() {
  var result;
  var num1= document.getElementById('num1').value;
  var num2= document.getElementById('num2').value;


  if (num1 > num2) {
     result = num1 - num2;
   } else {
    result = num2 - num1;
  }
  alert('The difference between the two numbers are: ' + result)
  }
  </script>


  <p>Enter your values</p>

  <input id="num1" type="number" placeholder=" Value 1">
  <input id="num2" type="number" placeholder=" Value 2">
  <button onclick="diff()">Press for Answer</button>
```